# Bootstrap React Modal Not displaying properly

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am trying to render a bootstrap modal in my React App [pretty much following the logic from the Bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/), except the open modal button is located in a different component.

The modal displays without any styling, at the bottom of the page and does not properly overlay the page and grey out the overlaid page as demonstrated in the documents. I am not that familiar with using Bootstrap in React so I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Here is where the bootstrap modal component is located:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import AppModal from './widgets/AppModal'

function App() {
  cacheUser(useAuth0)
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  function handleShow() {
    setShow(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AppModal onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} />
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>
[...]
 </>
```

And here is the actual modal code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'

export default function AppModal(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(props.show)
  }, [props.show])

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you add the bootstrap style file in `src/index.js` file.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```